Undefined Xelatex citation
I'm writing my dissertation in xelatex, however I'm having an issue where non of my citations are defined, and just appear as [?]. I'm using the same preamble I've used on other documents which did not have this issue. Occasionally they will all appear, this happened once as I started the document at the start of a day, but the next time I compiled the document they disappear again. This is my preamble:
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\usepackage{listings}


\usepackage{chngcntr} % For changing counter formats

% Reset figure counter within subsections
\counterwithin{figure}{subsection}

% Define figure numbering format
\renewcommand\thefigure{\thesubsection.\arabic{figure}}



\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\setmainfont{Arial}
\newfontfamily\tnr{Times New Roman} 
\newfontfamily\cam{Cambria} 
\subsectionfont{\fontspec{Cambria Bold Italic}\fontsize{14}{16.8}\selectfont}

\subsubsectionfont{\fontspec{Cambria Bold Italic}\fontsize{14}{16.8}\selectfont}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}


\newcommand{\finalfont}{\fontsize{24pt}{1.15pt}\selectfont\bfseries} % Bold variant applied here
\newcommand{\titlefont}{\fontsize{15pt}{1pt}\selectfont\bfseries} % Bold variant applied here
\newcommand{\namefont}{\fontsize{15pt}{1pt}\selectfont\bfseries} % Bold variant applied here
\newcommand{\individualfont}{\fontsize{12pt}{1.15pt}\selectfont\rmfamily} % Using regular font here
\newcommand{\certifyfont}{\fontsize{11pt}{1.15pt}\selectfont\rmfamily} % Using regular font here
\newcommand{\signedfont}{\fontsize{12pt}{1pt}\selectfont\bfseries} % Bold variant applied here
\newcommand{\collagefont}{\fontsize{11pt}{1pt}\selectfont\rmfamily}
\newcommand{\unifont}{\fontsize{11pt}{1pt}\selectfont\rmfamily}
\newcommand{\abfont}{\fontsize{16pt}{1.15pt}\selectfont\bfseries}
\newcommand{\abstractfont}{\fontsize{11pt}{1pt}\selectfont\tnr\itshape}
\newcommand{\keywordfont}{\fontsize{12pt}{1.15pt}\selectfont\tnr\itshape}

\geometry{
    left=2.54cm,
    right=2.54cm,
    top=2.54cm,
    bottom=2.54cm
}







\begin{document}

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
I've tried coping both the .bib file and the main document to new documents and recompiling, I've tried running on both xelatex and lunatex. As I said before, sometimes the citations appear but most of the time the appear as [?]

Welcome to TeX.SE. Do you run BibTeX after running XeLaTeX? This is needed to produce the references. Do you get any errors or warnings when you run BibTeX?

It would be an improvement if you would format your example as code.  To do that, highlight the code block with your mouse, then click on the () icon above the question box.  (I could do it, but then my name, not yours, would appear in the question list, and that's misleading.)

\fontsize{16pt}{1.15pt} means 16pt high letters on lines that are 1.15pt apart??  TeX will not be able to maintain that impossibly small baselineslip so lines will be spaced inconsistently, depending on the height of any letters that happen to be on each line.

getting [?] is the expected output until you generate a bibliography with bibtex and then re-run xelatex twice more.
